# context.startForegroundService(startServiceIntent) multiple time will call onCreate multiple times?

Tags: android, service

If I call context.startForegroundService(startServiceIntent) multiple time, will I call onCreate() with a new service intent multiple times or I will I call the first time onCreate for a new service intent and then call onStartCommand()/onHandleIntent() multiple times?

Comment: you can try this while making log statements very easily.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends if the service is running or not. `startForegroundService()` will trigger a call to `onCreate()` if that service is not already running.

So, for example:

- You call `startForegroundService()`
- Android creates an instance of your service and calls `onCreate()` on it
- Android then calls `onStartCommand()` on it (which may trigger calls to other things, like `onHandleIntent()` of `IntentService`)
- You call `startForegroundService()` again
- Android realizes that you have a running copy of the service and does not create a new one, so there is no `onCreate()` call
- Android then calls `onStartCommand()` on it (which may trigger calls to other things, like `onHandleIntent()` of `IntentService`)
- You stop your service, via something like `stopService()` or `stopSelf()` (or `onHandleIntent()` returns, if you are still using `IntentService`)
- You call `startForegroundService()` again, because you really like that method
- Android creates an instance of your service and calls `onCreate()` on it
- Android then calls `onStartCommand()` on it (which may trigger calls to other things, like `onHandleIntent()` of `IntentService`)

Comment: Ha great! So it leads me to another question:
If Android realizes that I have a running copy of the service and does not create a new one, so there is no onCreate() call but onStartCommand(), will I have two workflow in parallel? (The one from onStartCOmmand() and the one that is still in onHandleIntent()?)

Comment: @AdrienBoukobza: You mention `onHandleIntent()`. That suggests that you are using `IntentService`. If so, then your commands are queued. `IntentService` has just one background thread. So it will process the first command. Then, if there is another command waiting, it will process that command. This continues until there are no more commands, at which time the `IntentService` calls `stopSelf()` and goes away. So, unless you screw up your `onHandleIntent()` implementation (e.g., do asynchronous work), only one command will be processed at a time.

Comment: Ha great! And if it is a normal service (not a serviceIntent)? Is it done in parallel?

Comment: @AdrienBoukobza: A plain `Service` has no threads. `onStartCommand()` will be called one at a time, as that is always called on the main application thread. Whether the two commands are processed in parallel or not depends entirely on what you do in `onStartCommand()`. For example, if you fire off two coroutines or use a thread pool or something, the work for those two commands might go on concurrently.